# Is a checksum a good way of determining if a file/string of text is the same from machine to machine?

Tags: checksum

I have heard, but I now cannot find evidence that a checksum can vary from machine to machine where the file is the same.  Is that true?  We are considering relying on a checksum in our application that will be calculated on many different machines, will this be reliable?

Comment: Well that's what checksums were designed for. If the algorithm is the same then the checksum should be the same from machine to machine; if it weren't, then what's the point?

Comment: You may want to use a cryptographic hash, like SHA1, instead. Checksums are fine, but not as reliable as a full-blown hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm. If you are using a multibyte (>8 bit) checksum that uses integer (two's complement) math, then you will get different results depending on the endianness of the machine.

This is why a lot of network checksum algorithms use [one's complement math instead](http://www.netfor2.com/checksum.html) of two's complement.

If both machines are the same OS and archtecture, you should be OK (unless your algorithm does something **really** weird).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you make sure you are using the same checksum algorithm, it will be fine.